Dependency injection in JavaFX application with Spring Boot
How do I properly use dependency injection in a Spring Boot application?
My software has a JavaFX main window and multiple sub-dialogs that are opened and closed from the main window. I need to use REST clients in the sub-dialogs that are injected by Spring Boot. However, each client instance requires a constructor parameter for initialization.
So I end up with a multitude of REST clients in my main window's controller that are then passed down to the controllers of the sub-dialogs. Is there any better way to implement this to get rid of all the constructor parameters?
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class MainController {

  private final FirstClient first;
  private final SecondClient second;
  private final ThirdClient third;

  @Autowired
  public MainController(FirstClient first, SecondClient second, ThirdClient third) {
    this.first = first;
    this.second = second;
    this.third = third;
  }

  private void openSubDialog() {
    // ...
    SubController subController = new SubController(first, second);
    // ...
  }

  private void openAnotherSubDialog() {
    // ...
    AnotherSubController anotherSubController = new AnotherSubController(first, third);
    // ...
  }

}

My controller classes are annotated with @Component and @Scope("prototype").
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class SubController {

  private final FirstClient first;
  private final SecondClient second;

  @Autowired
  public SubController(FirstClient first, SecondClient second) {
    this.first = first;
    this.second = second;
  }

  private void doSomething() {
    var result = first.callSomeService();
  }

}

And finally, my REST clients look somewhat like this:
@Service
public class FirstClient {

  public SomeType callSomeService() {
    return restClient.getSomeData();
  }

}


I'm looking for a way to directly inject the REST clients in the controllers of the sub-dialogs without the need to add constructor parameters and pass them down from the main view. In pseudo-code, something like this:
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class ImprovedController {

  @InjectHereDirectly
  private final FirstClient first;

  @InjectHereDirectly
  private final SecondClient second;

  // No constructor needed

  private void doSomething() {
    var result = first.callSomeService();
  }

}


what do you mean: "each client instance requires a constructor parameter for initialization.". are they not within the spring context?

When defining a REST client in the sub-controllers, my IDE warns that the variable might not have been initialized and demands adding a constructor parameter. My client classes are annotated with @Service.

and have you autowired your controller in your client?

Not sure what you are asking. The REST clients know nothing about the JavaFX controllers. The JavaFX controllers are provided by an FXMLLoader.

But you need the controllers to be spring-managed, otherwise spring cannot inject anything. Are you doing that? I don't really understand what you are asking either. "Is there a better way to implement this" Define "better". What are your criteria for making it "good"? "to get rid of all the constructor parameters". Why do you want to get rid of the constructor parameters?

Better in terms that I don't want to pass the REST client objects down from the MainController. Some of them I don't even need in the MainController, I'm simply defining them there, because they are needed in one of the sub-dialogs (launched from the main view).

My controllers are annotated with @Component and my REST clients are annotated with @Service. Doesn't that make them Spring-managed?

I've updated my question to clarify. Thanks for taking the time!

They're only spring-managed if you are getting the controller instances from the spring ioc container. It doesn't make sense to talk about classes being spring-managed, it's about where the instances come from. If you are instantiating the controllers by hand (new SubController(...) etc., then obviously they are not spring-managed. The whole point of spring is that it manages object creation and dependency for you.

If these are controllers in the "FXML" sense, then you just need to tell the FXMLLoader to get the controllers from spring.

I'll investigate that further, but it will likely solve my issue. Thank you, @James_D! If anybody else reading this is wondering, how to exactly "get the controller from Spring", check this answer.

Solution:
Spring Boot allows you to inject dependencies via an annotation. This works, but it is recommended by Spring Boot theirself to use the constructor injection.
@Autowired
private final FirstClient first;

Experimental workaround:
You can achieve this using the Lombok library.
Step 1: Include the Lombok dependency:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
    <version>...</version>
</dependency>

Step 2: Use the @RequiredArgsConstructor like this:
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UiController {

    private final TodoRepository todoRepository;

}

Info: A working template application is provided in this git repo:
https://github.com/davidweber411/javafx-JavaFxSpringBootMavenApp

Don’t use Lombok with JavaFX

Why not? An explanation would be useful.

Lombok makes all kinds of assumptions (at least using the defaults) about the relationship between method names, constructor and accessor method parameter names and types, and field names and types. The JavaFX property pattern conforms to the Java Bean pattern but doesn't use the specific implementation that Lombok assumes. So using Lombok with JavaFX often results in unexpected behavior, or things that simply don't work.

Irrespective of the use of Lombok, this answer doesn't actually seem to address the actual question, which is how to avoid having the MainController retain references to the services solely for the purpose of providing them to the other controllers.

IMO it is exactly what answers the question: "However, each client instance requires a constructor parameter for initialization... Is there any better way to implement this to get rid of all the constructor parameters?" And look at the example code solution he provided: @InjectHereDirectly field. Both solutions in my answer are 100% answering his question.

this answer doesn't actually seem to address the actual question, which is how to avoid having the MainController retain references to the services solely for the purpose of providing them to the other controllers. : Dependency injection = Inject dependencies where they are needed. If "other" controllers need the injections, make them a Spring component and use dependency injection in their own classes.

Pure services should always be spring components in Spring Boot. They allow dependency injection in their own class and this is the way to go.
